# Redeclaring opaque struct in C file

Tags: c, struct

I'm working on a header file that declares some opaque `struct`s which is supposed to be defined in the corresponding C file. Here it is:

`decl.h`

```
#ifndef DECL_H
#define DECL_H

typedef struct test_t test;

#endif //
```

Some library that is supposed to be used in the implementation defines another opaque struct in its header `lib.h`:

```
//...
typedef struct _library_struct_t library_struct;
//...
```

Now in my `decl.c` file I want to make `struct test_t` to be the same (or compatible) with the `library_struct`. I tried this:

`decl.c`

```
//...
typedef library_struct test; //error: conflicting types for ‘test’
//...
```

But it does not compile. So the only way to go I can see now is

```
struct test_t{
    library_struct *lib_struct_ptr;
};
```

Is there shorter or more convenient way? Both `test` and `library_struct` are opaque. Why can't I make the `test` to be the same as `library_struct`? Can macros be helpful here?

Comment: "*I want to make A be the same as B*" Why?

Comment: @alk in the C file I am planning to use library functions opeating on `library_struct`. So it would help to avoid that boilerplate with extacting a `library_struct*`from `struct test_t` every time.

Comment: You've created a new user-defined type `library_struct`, and then created `test`, a new user-defined type which is of type `library_struct`; so in essence you've created a type from a type.  I'm not quite sure why you would want to do this?

Comment: Why not `typedef library_struct test;`? Users of your header still get to use just `test`; the fact that it's really `struct _library_struct_t` is just a detail behind the scenes.

Comment: @aschepler because the library is platform-specific so different libraries will be used for different platforms.

Comment: Have you considered using `struct test_t { library_struct x; };`, that is, making the `library_struct` the first and only member in your `struct test_t`? Your type would be opaque to your users. Inside your library, you would use the member inside your struct to interact with the library you are using. The code would be slight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is equivalent to

```
typedef struct test_t test; /* from decl.h */
typedef library_struct test; /* in decl.c */
```

So you redefine *test* and of course the compiler doesn't accept that

I don't know what you expect to do through macros but redefinition is not allowed.

In the worst case you can hide the type of a pointer with a `void *` then casting to the type you (hope) have, but this is obviously dangerous because the compiler will follow you **at your own risk**.

The compiler does not check the types against you but to help you to see your errors at compile time ...

Comment: I agree. This is not possible because `typedef` name refers to different types. `6.7(p3)`: `a typedef name may be redefined to denote the same type as it currently does, provided that type is not a variably modified type`